# 2003 Dodge Durango - Can I take the front drive shaft off and drive the vehicle?

Tags: dodge, drivetrain, 4wd, differential, durango

I most likely have a messed up front differential on my 4x4.

I was wondering if I can just take my drive shaft off and run it on RWD only?

Can I just remove the universal joint pin and retain the rest inside the front diff?

Comment: If you have an open centre diff, then you will get no drive at all. If you have a centre diff lock, then you could put that on to get drive.

Comment: How would I know which one I got

Comment: I don't know the vehicle, but there would usually be some kind of lever or switch to put a diff lock on if it had one.

Comment: You can remove the driveshaft and safely drive the truck, but why do you think the front diff is messed up?

Comment: @HandyHowie it's a 4x4 with either a automatic transfer case or a push button.

Answer (score 2):

Most 4x4 vehicles (as opposed to all wheel drive) do not have a differential in the transfer case. The Dodge Durango, has a non-differential transfer case, meaning that the front and rear drive shafts will spin at the same speed all the time in 4 wheel drive.

There shouldn't be any problem with removing your front drive shaft and driving your vehicle.

As a general rule, if you can switch the vehicle between 2wd and 4wd, there is no differential in the transfer case.

Comment: For reference : http://auto.howstuffworks.com/four-wheel-drive2.htm